# Read Text File and Return Words as a Sorted List

Tags: python, python-3.x

For an assignment in Python 3, I need to create a program that will do the following:

1. Open a text file chosen by the user
2. Append all words within text file to a list
3. Sort the words in the list
4. Print the sorted list matching the desired results

The code I have will sort the list but will not dedup the list to the desired results. The text file is the first four lines of a soliloquy from Romeo and Juliet.

```
fname = input("Enter file name: ")
fh = open(fname)
lst = list()
for line in fh:
    line = line.rstrip()
    words = line.split()
    for word in words:
        lst.append(word)
lst.sort()
print(lst)
```

The desired result is:

```
['Arise', 'But', 'It', 'Juliet', 'Who', 'already', 'and', 'breaks', 'east', 'envious', 'fair', 'grief', 'is', 'kill', 'light', 'moon', 'pale', 'sick', 'soft', 'sun', 'the', 'through', 'what', 'window', 'with', 'yonder']
```

But with my code, I get duplicated words:

```
['Arise', 'But', 'It', 'Juliet', 'Who', 'already', 'and', 'and', 'and', 'breaks', 'east', 'envious', 'fair', 'grief', 'is', 'is', 'is', 'kill', 'light', 'moon', 'pale', 'sick', 'soft', 'sun', 'sun', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'through', 'what', 'window', 'with', 'yonder']
```

How can I dedupe the list?

Comment: It must be a list? Can't you use [Sets](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing duplicates in lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961363/removing-duplicates-in-lists)

Comment: `print(list(set(lst)))` will yield the correct result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways you can do this. You can check if the word is already in the list, and only append when the word is not in the list:

```
for word in words:
    if word not in lst:
        lst.append(word)
lst.sort()
```

If the word is already in the list, you don't do anything, so I think that is all you need.

You can also convert your list to a set (sets can only have a single instance of each unique value they contain). The kind of clunky thing about this is that you will then need to convert it back to a list to sort it (sets are unsorted by nature, although there are other libraries that give you sorted options), and to match the required output format (I assume they require a *list* output):

```
for word in words:
    lst.append(word)
lst = sorted(set(lst))  # convert to set and sort in one line. Returns a list.
```

I'd assume the first option seems more illustrative of what you are likely expected to be learning for this assignment.

Comment: I knew I was missing a small detail somewhere

Comment: @PatrickArtner right you are on `sorted(set(whatever))`. Updated. I kept the `for` loop because `lst` is being built as he reads through line-by-line. Wouldn't `set(words)` give an independent set *per line*, and then replace it on the next line? Sure, you could do things to get around this elegantly, but elegant is often not very readable or instructive, and I was trying to make minimal modifications to his existing code. Homework problem, after all.

Comment: You are right, I read the OP only half and yours not good enough - you would need something along `sorted( {word for line in fh for word in line.rstrip().split()} )` and `with open(...) as fh:` to get it in one go. and thats not as readable for homework-level.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of list, use set to collect words. At the end, convert to list and sort

```
fname = input("Enter file name: ")
words = set()
with open(fname) as fh:
    for line in fh:
        line = line.rstrip()
        words.update(set(line.split()))

words_list = sorted(list(words))
print(words_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

One possibility would be to use a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set), maybe like this:

```
filename = input("Enter file name: ")
words = set()

with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        if len(line) > 0:
            for w in line.split()
                w = w.strip()
                if len(w) > 0:
                    words.add(w)

print(words)
sorted_words = list(sorted(words))
print(sorted_words)
```